# Elastic Search vs Azure Search

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to decide between Elastic Search and Azure Search.

I've found that they are very similar (except Azure Search supports multiple languages and has an AI for processing blobs and files and autocomplete).

But what made me think more was the price. For Elastic Search I have to pay $0.0615 per hour which means $44.28 per month (35GB storage | 1GB RAM | Up to 2.1 vCPU) and for the similar infrastructure Azure Cognitive Search the cost is $73.73 (Basic tier).
[image]
[image]

And going forward the price difference is very big.

Is anyone who can help with more details in this direction, please? Are there any hidden costs on Elastic search or why is this huge difference and nobody talks about that?

Answer (score 2):

The price is different because they are different products to solve different problems.

Elasticsearch is a search engine where you will have to build your own ingest pipeline and queries.

Azure Search is a Search-as-a-service platform that includes some AI features in the pipeline like NER (Named Entity Recognition) ,image detection, audio transcription, NLP, etc.

If you need all these features and don't want to implement them yourself, then you should go stick to Azure Search.